# lua crash after some time running when using wait() inside of while loop

Tags: lua

I am using SIMCOM 5320a chipset

I have a bare bone code with wait() function using os.clock() and a while loop with counter counting up.

However, After counting up to a certain number (around 1 minute), the program crash and the board restart itself.

My question is:

is this violate any rule when using while nest loop like this ?

Is there any replacement for using sleep/wait function in lua. Simcom has vmsleep but it will crash after roughly 7 hours of running.

I have try multiple sleep/wait function

I reduce my code to bare bone in order to debug

```
function sleep (a) 
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + (a/1000)); 
    while (os.clock() < sec) do 
    end 
end

function main()
 local count=0
    while (count < 130) do 
        count = count + 1  
        print("Nothing yet..".. count .. "\r\n");
        sleep(2000)
    end
end

main()
```

Comment: I know for sure sleep function will eat up a lot of CPU resources. That is why it crashing and restart the board itself.

Comment: `After counting up to a certain number (around 1 minute), the program crash and the board restart itself` it looks like a watchdog

Comment: watchdog in SIMCOM is around 2 minute or something. This only around 1 minute. I tried with multiple boards and the result are the same. They all crash within 52 second to 60 second approximately. And i disable watchdog with AT command too